# Search Service Application not getting created

Tags: 2013, search, web-services

[image]

I am trying to apply a content query web part & search web part in my site via SharePoint Designer 2013.

It shows some technical error. I have now realized that the search service application has not been configured at the time of installation.

When I am trying to create one it failed. What are the steps to do that?

Comment: Title says it's not starting, actual question says you cannot even create it. Which one is the case? Also please include error messages you're getting.

Comment: not getting created is the question ; log shows this :-                                 Unexpected Fetching app info failed: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchServiceNotFoundException: The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy(SPServiceContext ServiceContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchCommon.GetSearchCenterUrl() 0e17549d-88e0-c05a-67d3-f43304b3e56e

Comment: Do you see any old (possibly orphaned) Search SA with "Get-SPServiceApplication"?

Comment: no , at the time of SharePoint installation search service was not installed only

Answer (score 0):

The Search Service Application Proxy does probably not exist in the farm. The Search Service Application Proxy is responsible for the communication between the WFE's search web part and the Search Service Application on the application server.

Create a new proxy using PowerShell cmdlets:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;

$searchServiceApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy -SearchApplication $searchServiceApp
```

To first delete a Search Application, use:

```
STSADM.EXE -o deleteconfigurationobject -id <GUID of the service>
```

Comment: @Dj21 First try this and let us know if it had any result.

Comment: I ran ur commands in powershell , I gt display name , typename-search service app , ID .... now what next?

Comment: @DJ21 Verify in the SP admin site that the search service is running and your webpart is working without errors.

Comment: ok , bt we have to create one search service application right o not ?

Comment: yes , I will put it right away just give me few minutes.

Comment: @Dj21 remove both search related services and run this in powershell: http://pastebin.com/iBYDPp7X It creates the search service for you.

Comment: the one with error is not getting deleted !!

Comment: yes , that is true but i don't have enough reputation to move it into chat

Comment: See my updated answer to delete a service

Comment: Please dont use that STSADM command if possible. Its not supported (And not documented also)